# database in php mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

I am writing a chat on php, when I try to log in, user_id is recorded in the session, after a successful attempt, a chat page appears where all the messages are written but the problem is that all the messages  were written by me, but it is not true. There are some messages which has been written by other users. So, how can I solve this problem by using JOIN? Can you give me some adive or improve my code?
This is code for log in:

```
<?php
session_start();
include 'db.php';
    if (isset($_POST['email-e']) && isset($_POST['password-pass'])) { 
    $email_e = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['email-e']);
    $password_pass = crypt($_POST['password-pass']);

    $query = "SELECT id, email, password FROM users_data WHERE email = '$email_e' AND password = '$password_pass'";
    $sql = mysqli_query($mysqli,$query) or die(mysqli_error());
    if (mysqli_num_rows($sql) == 1) {
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql);

    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $row['id'];
    $_SESSION['email-e'] = $row['email'];

    setcookie("CookieMy", $row['email'], time()+60*60*24*10);
  }
    else {
        echo 'User not found!';
      header("Location: login.html"); 
    }
  }
    if (isset($_SESSION['email-e'])){
     header("Location: chat.php");
    } else {
    $email_e = '';
    if (isset($_COOKIE['CookieMy'])){
        $email_e = htmlspecialchars($_COOKIE['CookieMy']);
    }
}
?>
```

This is chat.php code:

```
<?php
session_start();
include 'db_chat.php';
// header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
//echo trim($_SESSION['email-e'])." <br />"."You are authorized <br />";
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Chat</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<title>Chat</title>
<style>
form,p,span{margin:0;padding:0}
    input{font:12px arial}
    a{color:#00f;text-decoration:none}
    a:hover{text-decoration:underline}
    #wrapper,
    #loginform{margin:0 auto;padding-bottom:25px;background:#ebf4fb;width:504px;border:1px solid #acd8f0}#loginform{padding-top:18px}#loginform p{margin:5px}
    #chatbox{text-align:left;margin:0 auto;margin-bottom:25px;padding:10px;background:#fff;height:270px;width:430px;border:1px solid #acd8f0;overflow:auto}
    #usermsg{
        width:380px;
        height: 50px;
        border:1px solid #acd8f0;
        border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
    }
    #submitmsg{width:70px; height: 53px; border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px; cursor: pointer;}
    .error{color:#f00}
    #menu{padding:12.5px 25px 12.5px 25px}
    .welcome{float:left}
    .logout{float:right}
    .msgln{margin:0 0 2px 0}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="menu">
        <p class="welcome">Welcome, <?php echo trim($_SESSION['email-e'])?><b></b></p>
        <p class="logout" name="logout">
            <a name="logout" id="exit" href="#">Exit Chat</a>
        </p>
        <div style="clear:both"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="chatbox">
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submitmsg'])) {
    if(!empty($_POST['usermsg']) && is_string($_POST['usermsg'])) {
        $time =  date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
        $usermsg = trim($_POST['usermsg']);
        $sql_chat ="INSERT INTO `users_chat` (usermsg,time)
                    VALUES('{$usermsg}','{$time}')";
        $res = mysqli_query($mysqli_chat,$sql_chat);

    } 
}
        $query_chat = "SELECT * FROM `users_chat`";
        $res = mysqli_query($mysqli_chat,$query_chat);
        while($row_chat = mysqli_fetch_array($res)):?>
        <?php $_SESSION['user_id'] = $row_chat['id'];?>
        Email: <?=$row_chat['email-e']?> <br>
        Message: <?=$row_chat['usermsg']?> <br>
        Time: <?=$row_chat['time']?> <br>


<?php endwhile;?>
    </div>
<form  name="message"   action="" method="post">
<input name="usermsg"   type="text"   id="usermsg" style="margin-left:25px;">
<input name="submitmsg" type="submit" id="submitmsg" value="Send"/><br>
</form>    
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is structure of my users_chat table:

```
CREATE TABLE `users_chat` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `usermsg` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: Not really understand you issue... but how come in the insert query into users_chat you don't include your user id or email?

Comment: @AntonyGibbs db works good, all data inserts

Comment: Can you please provide the table structure of your "users_chat" Table?

Comment: @ABHI I added it it code. See, please

Comment: @Timur : - Why don't you mentioned username and user_id  in to you insert query?  $sql_chat ="INSERT INTO `users_chat` (usermsg,time)
                    VALUES('{$usermsg}','{$time}')";  It should be $sql_chat ="INSERT INTO `users_chat` (username,usermsg,user_id,time)
                    VALUES('{$username}','{$usermsg}',''{$user_id},'{$time}')";

Comment: @ABHI Because I do not have username, I write message using email. So, I tried your methd but it doesn`t work. I tried to print $_SESSION['user_id'], after that  $_SESSION['email-e'].

Comment: @Timur But in your "user_chat" table I didn't see any "email-e " column !!

Answer (score 0):

1. What is the structure of your *users_chat* table. I don't see you assign poster id to each message when insert to the database. You must have a field in your *users_chat* like *poster_id* which is the foreign key to the *users_data* table's id and run this sql in the handle POST request `INSERT INTO users_chat (poster_id, usermsg, time) VALUES('{$_SESSION["user_id"]}', '{$usermsg}','{$time}')`
2. `while($row_chat = mysqli_fetch_array($res)):?> 
   <?php $_SESSION['user_id'] = $row_chat['id'];?>`

   this will modify the user_id in the session to the id of the chat message, I don't think this is what you want.

Comment: @Timur see ABHI's comment

Comment: It didn't work is really vague, to help you we need more information. Can you go to your database manager (phpmyadmin or mysql workbench) and see what data is inserted there. Btw I see you print `$row['email-e']` in the while loop, there is no field `email-e` in your users_chat table.